# How to read user from request in a Mongoose midddleware hook or a service in NestJS

Tags: express, mongoose, nestjs

Assume a user is logged in and there is a `Post` document, I want to save the user who created and updated the post.

```js
export interface Post extends Document {
  readonly title: string;
  readonly content: string;
  readonly createdAt?: Date;
  readonly updatedAt?: Date;
  readonly createdBy?: User;
  readonly updatedBy?: User;
}

export const PostSchema = new Schema({
  title: SchemaTypes.String,
  content: SchemaTypes.String,
  createdAt: { type: SchemaTypes.Date, required: false },
  updatedAt: { type: SchemaTypes.Date, required: false },
  createdBy: { type: SchemaTypes.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: false },
  updatedBy: { type: SchemaTypes.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: false },
});
```

But I have no idea how to read the user from the request in a service component or Mongoose document schema.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? I want to achieve this too but didn't find any documentation about injecting service or request data in the schema to be accessed by the Mongoose middleware hook

Comment: @a7md0 Check [here](https://github.com/hantsy/nestjs-rest-sample/blob/master/src/post/post.service.ts)

Comment: I've checked the scoped service; However, it was not done using Mongoose middleware hook?

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on how you authenticate your users, but you should be able to intercept whichever access token, cookies (...) that the frontend uses to authentifies itself.
You can intercept it in the controller and get the corresponding user (or userId) which you can then pass to your service.

In case you're using nestjs passport, your example could look like this:

```
import { Injectable, Request, Body } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthGuard } from '@nestjs/passport';

@Injectable()
export class JwtAuthGuard extends AuthGuard('jwt') {}
```

```
import { Controller, Bind, Request, Post, UseGuards } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthGuard } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { JwtAuthGuard } from './auth/jwt-auth.guard';

@Controller()
export class PostController {
  @UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard)
  @Put('post')
  addPost(@Request() request, @Body() body) {
    const user = request.user._id;
    // We only need the id to add it to mongo but you could also pass the whole user
    return this.createPost(body, user._id)
  }
}
```

```
@Injectable()
class PostService
//...
async createPost(body, userId) {
  this.postModel.create({
    ...body,
    createdBy: userId
  })
}
//...
```

If you want more information about how to use nestjs passport and implement auth guards, see here [nestjs docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/security/authentication#implementing-passport-strategies)

Comment: This still doesn't answer the ability to access the request/user data from Mongoose middleware hook. Obviously passing the data as parameters would work, but isn't the cleanest approach